# Vet lost cat's microchip information

Tags: cats, identification

My two cats recently had microchips implanted. The vet, however, lost one of the cats information (entire envelope of information).

The vet scanned the microchip and wrote down the number associated (15 digits) on a card and said that's all we need.

My other cat came with sterility expiration + some extra number + stickers containing the barcode + various cards etc.

Am I missing any important information at this point, and if so, is there anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your vet will have registered most of the information about your cat on his PC, and the chip number contains information about the producer of the chip plus the unique number of the chip/cat.

Your vet will have to contact the company to get a copy of the papers for the chip, but this is your vet's problem and not yours. The vet can probably download the form from the company's website and register all the needed information directly.

Edit: I have changed the text, as the manufacturer of a chip is often not the same as the company where the registration is kept and updated when needed.

Comment: Ok thank you. I have had an email directly from the company that the vet had registered the chip with (not the manufacturer). I will ask them directly what information I am missing, if any. I would rather I didn't leave this to my vets to do as have now had a few negative experiences in a space of a couple of weeks.

Answer (score 5):

The chip number is important but so is the name of the company who stores the microchip information.

If ever you move you will need to contact the company to change the information, it is also good to have a copy of the paperwork in case mistakes were made when registering your pets. It will give you the opportunity to fix any errors.